# Python logging messages not showing up due to imports

Tags: python, logging

I have trouble with the `logging` module. I search through other answers, but can't find a suitable solution.

My code:

```
import logging

def configure_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s | [%(levelname)s] | %(message)s | function: %(funcName)s",
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_logging()

    # Logging message
    logging.info("Test")
    
    # Other stuff here
```

When run, this correctly outputs what is expected. Whenever I add another import like `from mypackage.mymodule import myfunction`, the logging output is no longer displayed.

I tried to look for patterns, but I checked and none of the imported modules imports the `logging` module, for instance. On the other hand, import of common libraries (such as numpy or pandas) does not make the issue appear.

An example of import that breaks the logging is the following:

```
import logging
# Suspicious import
from settings.constants import QUESTIONS_INFO

def configure_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s | [%(levelname)s] | %(message)s | function: %(funcName)s",
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_logging()

    # Logging message
    logging.info("Test")
    
    # Other stuff here
```

where `settings/constants.py` is the following:

```
from inputoutput.yaml import read_yaml

QUESTIONS_DEFINTION = read_yaml(f"settings/questions_definition.yml")
QUESTIONS_INFO = QUESTIONS_DEFINTION["questions"]
```

and where `inputoutput/yaml.py` is the following:

```
import logging
import yaml


def read_yaml(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path) as file:

            data = yaml.safe_load(file)
            file.close()
        logging.debug(f"Yaml file: {file_path} loaded")
        return data

    except Exception as message:
        logging.error(f"Impossible to load the file: {file_path}")
        logging.error(f"Error: {message}")
        return None
```

There's maybe some other argument that I need to add to the `basicConfig` function? Or maybe a way to correctly set up and call the logger here in main and in imported submodules?

Comment: Can you update the portion of the code, when it does not work ? That is more relevant to the question.

Comment: Edited, I added the chain of an import that breaks the logging. In this case the last module imported imports the `logging` module

Comment: Basically, you are running your log calls before configuring. The import works first, before calling the main. Try moving your import to next line after `configure_logging()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that something that you import calls `basicConfig`. (Or adds a Handler to the root logger some other way. Calling `logging.debug()` for example does that.) Once the root logger has a Handler `basicConfig` has no effect. You can override this behaviour by setting the `force` arg:

```py
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s | [%(levelname)s] | %(message)s | function: %(funcName)s",
        force=True # <-- HERE
    )
```

This will remove any previously added Handlers from the root logger. A better way to solve this though is that you set up your logging as early as possible so that you don't run into the problem of having to remove already configured Handlers.

Comment: so basically, to ensure that `basicConfig` does the job, logging configuration should be run before every import is done in the main program. Isn't that in contrast with good coding practices that would require to put all imports at the top of file?

Comment: @mattiatantardini The core problem is that your imports have side effects: they set up a logging handler. So you already violated some good coding practices, and to work around the problems that causes you have to put your imports after the basicConfig or use the `force` argument.

Comment: It is a bit frustrating to me that this happens under the hood, just using a basic command from the logging module. But probably this is due to my not so deep understanting of its functioning. Your solution works, thank you.